# Why does IS NOT TRUE yield different results from != 't' in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a simple query. The value of drink_deleted is NULL.

This query returns the row:

```
SELECT * FROM drinks
WHERE drink_id = 1 
AND drink_deleted IS NOT TRUE
```

Originally I was trying to get the row with these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM drinks
WHERE drink_id = 1 
AND drink_deleted != 't'
```

```
SELECT * FROM drinks
WHERE drink_id = 1 
AND drink_deleted <> 't'
```

No result was returned in these cases. What's the reason for this? Is it  not possible to target NULL values with standard comparison operators in Postgres?

Comment: `a IS NOT TRUE` is not the same as `NOT a`.

Comment: *Is it not possible to target NULL values with standard comparison operators in Postgres?* That is correct you **cannot use** standard comparison operators with NULL. They always return NULL as the result when either or both operands are null. So, for example, `null = null` returns **null** not true.